# Add items to an array

Tags: php, arrays

My knowledge of PHP arrays is limited. I have read the [PHP Arrays - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), but it did not explain this in enough value for me to grasp it honestly.

I have the following in a `if{} else{}` statement with this being the `else{}`

```
// Set up an array for the items

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $source = $row['source'];
}

$items = array(
   "id" => $id,
   "source" => $source,
);

$_SESSION['items'] = $items;
```

Let's say I have the following items:

```
Item A with an ID of 1 and source of foo
Item B with an ID of 2 and source of boo
Item C with an ID of 3 and source of goo
```

If this function gets called with `item A`, the array is created with an id of `1` and source of `foo` and that is all that is placed in the array. And the array is dumped out like:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "25" ["source"]=> string(64) "https://www.alphahq.org/shop/views/assets/images/items/item2.jpg" }
```

Now what if the function gets called again for `item B` right now as it sets, the array will changed to the variables for `item B` **Correct?**

How would I be able to add `item A` and `item B` to the same array and define them as separate items?

So basically how could I do the following?

```
array {
  item A {
    id => 1
    source => foo
  }
  item B {
    id => 2
    source => boo
  }
}
```

And just build the array as an item is added. I am saving the array in a session, could this be helpful in retrieving and adding to the array each time the function is called?

Just for additional help, my full `shopping-functions.php` file is included below for reference.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require('../../config/database-connect.php');

    // Start a new order for a customer
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $id     = $_GET['id'];

    // First make sure the action is not blank
    if ($action == '') {

        echo 'Please select an action';
    }

    if ($action == 'add') {

        // Check if the id matches one in the database
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, source FROM items WHERE id='$id'");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

            echo 'That id is not valid!';
        }
        else {
            // Set up an array for the items

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $source = $row['source'];
            }

            $items = array(
                "id" => $id,
                "source" => $source,
            );

            var_dump($items);

            $_SESSION['items'] = $items;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
array_push — Push one or more elements onto the end of array
```

...Has the same effect as:

```
$array[] = $var;
```

Let's apply that to your case:

```
$items = array(); // Has to be initialised first, somewhere in your code
// ....
// Then after your while loop
$new_item = array("id" => $id, "source" => $source);

array_push($items, $new_item); // Append $new_item inside $items as its last value.
```

Answer (score 0):

First do this:

```
$items = []; // It's a good practice to initialize first
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $items[] = [ // Append to end of array
       "id" => $id,
       "source" => $row['source'], // Key with source
    ];
}
 // Here if you var_dump($items) you will see the result
```

Comment: This is okay, but you also need to initialize $items somewhere as `$items = array();` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: This looks like it could work although, I Hate being spoon fed i'm not just going to copy and paste. Please explain within your answer of your code. Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $source = $row['source'];
    $items = array(
        "id"     => $id,
        "source" => $source,
    );
    $_SESSION['items'][] = $items;
}

Multi - dimensional array
```

You probably want to store another array in  `$_SESSION['items'];` which makes it a multi-dimensional array.

`[]` will stack the next fed values to the next available key.

It means the first value of `$item` will be stored in `$_SESSION['items'][0]`, the second value of `$item` will be stored in `$_SESSION['items'][1]`, and so on...

Comment: This looks like it could work although, I **Hate** being spoon fed i'm not just going to copy and paste. Please explain within your answer of your code. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: i added some explanation but for better understanding i would recommend you a better multi dimensional arrays tutorial on google. there are many many available

Comment: This doesn't seem to be building. I added a foreach method to echo out each array. http://alphahq.org/shop/config/functions/shopping-functions.php?action=add&id=65 please click and then change 65 to 25 and you will see what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean? I added: foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $key) {
        
        echo "<hr>" .$id. " is equal to the source: " .$source. "<br/>";
       } in my code and I only see the id that is currently in the url for the script to get. Rather than a list of all of them previously entered.

Comment: how can you expect multiple values in an array when you are just feeding it once.. check my updated answer you might get a hint of what you were doing wrong.

Comment: So how am I supposed to bring out item A and item B when they are added to the array. To display in a shopping cart for example. If my foreach is only going to display one array. I can't hard code [0], [1] ... because I don't know how many items the user will add to the cart.

Comment: `foreach($items as $single_item){ echo $single_item[source]; }`

Answer (score 0):

For this case

```
// Based on pr1nc3's answer
$_SESSION['items'] = array(); // Create a new array

foreach($myResult as $row)
    $_SESSION['items'][] = $row;
```

The `[]` is the magic here: it says to PHP "Take the array identified before `[]` and push this item onto it" - in fact, this is essentially a shorthand for the `array_push` method:

```
$a = $b = array();
$c = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

foreach($c as $value) {
    $a[] = $value;
    array_push($b, $value);
}
```

After the above, `$a` and `$b` will look the same in a `var_dump` call.